# How do I extract specific characters from a cell?

Tags: excel, vba

Trying to extract then move same type of characters from one cell to another separate cells.

> Hallway 11.2-27.6 Outdoor.

or

> Middle Hallway 612-476 Back Outdoor.

To:

- **CELL(1)**: Hallway - Outdoor
- **CELL(1)**: Middle Hallway - Back Outdoor
- **CELL(2)**:11.2
- **CELL(3)**:27.6

Tried some regex and variables but no luck. couldn't get the logic.

The expected result is:

[image]

**Hallway - Outdoor   11.2   27.6**
or
**Middle Hallway - Back Outdoor   612   476**

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this short macro:

```
Sub parseit()
    Dim cell As Range

    For Each cell In Selection
        arr = Split(cell.Text, " ")
        cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = arr(0) & " - " & arr(2)
        brr = Split(arr(1), "-")
        cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = brr(0)
        cell.Offset(0, 3).Value = brr(1)
    Next cell
End Sub
```

[image]

**EDIT#1:**

This version can handle multiple words before and after the measurements:

```
Sub ParseIt2_The_Sequel()
    Dim cell As Range, special As String

    For Each cell In Selection
        special = ""
        arr = Split(cell.Text, " ")
        For i = LBound(arr) To UBound(arr)
            If InStr(arr(i), "-") > 0 Then
                special = arr(i)
                arr(i) = "-"
            End If
        Next i
        cell.Offset(0, 1).Value = Join(arr, " ")
        brr = Split(special, "-")
        cell.Offset(0, 2).Value = brr(0)
        cell.Offset(0, 3).Value = brr(1)
    Next cell

End Sub
```

[image]

Comment: hi, thanks for reply. when the LOCATION titles have more then 1 word like COMMON SALOON or MIDDLE HALLWAY the cod acts weird. how can i solve it. thanks.

`COMMON SALOON 430-22 MIDDLE HALLWAY
to
COMMON - HALLWAY SALOON 430 22 MIDDLE`

Comment: @CanKaracan  The code was designed with your example in mind.  If you update your original question with a complete list of the possible input forms, I will attempt to update my posted code.

Comment: after tryouts with your macro yes example is updated.

Comment: @CanKaracan  See my **EDIT#1**.

Comment: thanks for updated code. couldnt manage to resolve this issue.
**CELL(A)** COMMON SALOON 430-22 MIDDLE HALLWAY
`ParseIt2_The_Sequel` results this cell to:
**CELL(B)**COMMON - HALLWAY **CELL(C)** SALOON 430 **CELL(D)** 22 MIDDLE

Comment: can we add =PROPER formula to make text as i wanted insde of the code. thatd be solve the problem at last. Thanks alot

Answer (score 0):

If you put `Hallway 11.2-27.6 Outdoor` in Cell **A2**, you can get [your outcome](https://i.stack.imgur.com/xZFpG.png) with the following formulas:

Cell **B2**: `=SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(A2,C2,""),D2,"")`

Cell **C2**: `=SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A2,FIND(" ",A2,1)+1,20),"-",REPT("!",30)),20),"!","")`

Cell **D2**: `=SUBSTITUTE(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A2,FIND("-",A2,1)+1,99)," ",REPT("!",30)),20),"!","")`

What this is doing is finding the area around the dash and then inserting a bunch of ! marks and then removing. If you break out each step you can sort of follow along.

Here's two other options for c and d formulas

`=MID(A3,FIND(" ",A3,1)+1,FIND("-",A3,1)-FIND(" ",A3,1)-1)+0`
`=TRIM(LEFT(SUBSTITUTE(MID(A3,FIND("-",A3,1)+1,99)," ",REPT(" ",99)),40))+0`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to extract the numbers and join whatever is left, using regex, you can do something like this:

```
Sub ExtractValues(ByVal inputString As String, _
                  ByRef targetCell1 As Range, _
                  ByRef targetCell2 As Range, _
                  ByRef targetCell3 As Range)
    Dim regEx As New RegExp
    With regEx
        .Global = True
        .Pattern = "^(.+\s)(\d+(?:\.\d+))?-(\d+(?:\.\d+))(\s.+)$"
    End With

    Dim matches As MatchCollection
    Set matches = regEx.Execute(inputString)
    If matches.Count = 1 Then
        Dim m As Match: Set m = matches(0)
        targetCell1.Value = m.SubMatches(0) + "-" + m.SubMatches(3)
        targetCell2.Value = m.SubMatches(1)
        targetCell3.Value = m.SubMatches(2)
    End If
End Sub
```

**Usage:**

```
Sub Test()
    ExtractValues Range("A1").Value, Range("E1"), Range("F1"), Range("G1")
End Sub
```

**Result:**

[image: Result]

Comment: hi, couldnt call the macro with ExtractValues.
`Sub ExtractValues(ByVal inputString As String, _`

Comment: @CanKaracan If you're going to assign a macro to a button or something similar, you should add the line `ExtractValues Range("A1").Value, Range("E1"), Range("F1"), Range("G1")` in another sub and then use the other sub as the macro for your button. Check the edit.

Comment: created 2 modules, Sub ExtractValues, and Sub Test().
created button for call Test macro. When clicked a button it gives an error: **User-defined type not defined** and selects the  `regEx As New RegExp`

Comment: @CanKaracan You need to add a reference to `Microsoft VBScript Regular Expressions 5.5`. I thought since you asked for a regex solution you'd be aware of that. Anyway, you can do that by going to the "Tools" menu, then "References", then find and select the said reference.

Answer (score 0):

Try this code

```
Sub Test()
Dim a, x, i&

a = Range("A2:A" & Cells(Rows.Count, 1).End(xlUp).Row).Resize(, 3).Value
For i = LBound(a) To UBound(a)
    x = Split(a(i, 1))

    a(i, 1) = x(0) & " - " & x(UBound(x))
    a(i, 2) = Split(x(1), "-")(0)
    a(i, 3) = Split(x(1), "-")(1)
Next i
Range("F2").Resize(UBound(a, 1), UBound(a, 2)).Value = a
End Sub
```

Comment: hi, gets error in `a(i, 1) = x(0) & " - " & x(UBound(x))` for Middle 11.2-27.6 Outdoor
cell.

Answer (score 0):

If you have Excel 2016+ with the `TEXTJOIN` function, you can use this **array** formula for the location:

```
=TEXTJOIN(" ",TRUE,FILTERXML("<t><s>" &SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(REPLACE($A2,MIN(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},$A2&"0123456789")),0,CHAR(160)&CHAR(32)),"-"," "))," ","</s><s>"),CHAR(160),"-")&"</s></t>","//s[not(number())]"))
```

Since this is an array formula, you need to "confirm" it by holding down <kbd>ctrl</kbd> + <kbd>shift</kbd> while hitting <kbd>enter</kbd>.  If you do this correctly, Excel will place braces `{...}` around the formula as observed in the formula bar

For the two measurements, use (normal formulas):

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE($A2,"-"," "))," ","</s><s>")& "</s></t>","//s[number()>0][1]")
```

and

```
=FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE($A2,"-"," "))," ","</s><s>")& "</s></t>","//s[number()>0][2]")
```

[image]

The algorithm:

- Remove the hyphen from the original string
- Insert some non-used character before the first digit (I used the NBSP)
- Replace the hyphen with a space
- Replace the NBSP with a hyphen (to hyphenate the first and last text substrings
- Use the spaces as node markers to create an XML document
- Return and join the non-numeric nodes as the location
- Return the 1st and 2nd numeric nodes for the measurements

**EDIT**

If you have a finite number of words (+ the hyphen) that might be present at the beginning and ends of the strings, and you don't have the `TEXTJOIN` function, but do have Excel 2013 which has the `FILTERXML` function, you can use the following concatenation (entered normally).

You will need to repeat this:

```
IFERROR(FILTERXML("<t><s>" &SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(REPLACE($A1,MIN(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},$A1&"0123456789")),0,CHAR(160)&CHAR(32)),"-"," "))," ","</s><s>"),CHAR(160),"-")&"</s></t>","//s[not(number())][1]")&" ","")
```

for each possible word.  Note the `[1]`.  This gets incremented for each **non-numeric** word.

So for your data, assuming there is a maximum of 5 words + the hyphen to be concatenated, you would use the following formula:

```
=TRIM(CONCATENATE(
IFERROR(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(REPLACE($A1,MIN(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},$A1&"0123456789")),0,CHAR(160)&CHAR(32)),"-"," "))," ","</s><s>"),CHAR(160),"-")&"</s></t>","//s[not(number())][1]")&" ",""),
IFERROR(FILTERXML("<t><s>"&SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(REPLACE($A1,MIN(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},$A1&"0123456789")),0,CHAR(160)&CHAR(32)),"-"," "))," ","</s><s>"),CHAR(160),"-")&"</s></t>","//s[not(number())][2]")&" ",""),
IFERROR(FILTERXML("<t><s>" &SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(REPLACE($A1,MIN(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},$A1&"0123456789")),0,CHAR(160)&CHAR(32)),"-"," "))," ","</s><s>"),CHAR(160),"-")&"</s></t>","//s[not(number())][3]")&" ",""),
IFERROR(FILTERXML("<t><s>" &SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(REPLACE($A1,MIN(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},$A1&"0123456789")),0,CHAR(160)&CHAR(32)),"-"," "))," ","</s><s>"),CHAR(160),"-")&"</s></t>","//s[not(number())][4]")&" ",""),
IFERROR(FILTERXML("<t><s>" &SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(REPLACE($A1,MIN(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},$A1&"0123456789")),0,CHAR(160)&CHAR(32)),"-"," "))," ","</s><s>"),CHAR(160),"-")&"</s></t>","//s[not(number())][5]")&" ",""),
IFERROR(FILTERXML("<t><s>" &SUBSTITUTE(SUBSTITUTE(TRIM(SUBSTITUTE(REPLACE($A1,MIN(FIND({0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9},$A1&"0123456789")),0,CHAR(160)&CHAR(32)),"-"," "))," ","</s><s>"),CHAR(160),"-")&"</s></t>","//s[not(number())][6]")&" ","")))
```

**Results using the 2013 formula**

[image]

Comment: hi Ron, thanks for your concern. Can we do this with 2013?

Comment: @CanKaracan Unfortunately, 2013 does not have the `TEXTJOIN` function.

Comment: is there any luck for working through Google sheets?

Comment: @CanKaracan I've not tried it with Sheets. But give it a try and let us know.  I've posted a lengthy formula which shows an adaptation which should work in 2013. It should be usable unless you have a large number of **text** words in the string to be concatenated.  It basically concatenates one at a time.